# Orientdb community edition 2.0 intallation steps for window bit 64

Tags: orientdb

Hi need Steps for installing orientdb 2.0 in windows.Followed the link http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/Windows-Service.html
any better easy steps or video tutorial may helpful.

Answer (score -1):

1. Unzip orientdb 2.0.5 distribution
2. from command:  \bin\server.bat
3. Choose a password then go to http://localhost:2480/ from your
       favorite browser